# A bag contains $4$ red, $6$ white and $2$ blue balls. How many combinations?

Tags: probability, combinations

How many combinations of $6$ balls are there if at least one white ball and exactly $3$ red balls are selected?

I thought about separating it to $3$ cases - 
$1$ white ball, $2$ white balls and $3$ white balls. Then multiplying it all.

There is another way?
Thanks.

Comment: Are balls of a given colour identical?

Comment: @GoodDeeds No,Differenet.

Answer (score 2):

> How many combinations there are to pick up 6 balls but at least one white ball and 3 red balls exactly.

Do you mean "at least 1 white and exactly 3 red balls"?  Then:

- How many ways are there to pick three balls from the four red balls?
- How many ways are there to select three not-red balls(at least one of which is white) from the six white and two blue balls?

Answer (score 1):

There are three different case:

1)You choose 3 red balls,1 white ball and 2 blue balls
$$\binom{4}{3} * \binom {6}{1} * \binom {2}{2}$$
2)You choose 3 red balls, 2 white balls and 1 blue ball
$$\binom{4}{3} * \binom{6}{2} * \binom{2}{1}$$
3)You choose 3 red balls, 3 white balls and 0 blue balls
$$\binom{4}{3} * \binom{6}{3}$$
You then add each cases result together $24 + 120 + 80 = 224$ different combinations

Answer (score 0):

YOu just have 3 cases:

(3 RED, 2 BLUE, 1 WHITE) +

(3 RED, 1 BLUE, 2 WHITE) +

(3 RED, 3 WHITE)

Add these 3 cases.

Comment: Hint: the case you *don't* count is (3 RED, 0 WHITE, 3...wait there are only 2 blue balls)  so...